# Labels in Asymptote acting strangely

Tags: texmaker, asymptote

When adding a label to my Asymptote figure in Texmaker (for example, labeling a dot with the letter *A*), it doesn't update the pdf viewer with the newer figure (with the label) after a Quick Build unless I close the file, delete all of the files in my folder besides `Document.tex`, and open `Document.tex` and Quick Build again.

Here's an image of the contents of the folder my files are in:

[image]

The code for `Document.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{asy}
\dot((0,0));
\end{asy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Hard to say because your do not disclose your document. At least if you are using `asypictureB` it will recompile the asymptote file if you made changes to the `.asy` file.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm not sure what `asypictureB` is. Also, now I can't event run the asymptote code. I am getting an error: `file 'Document-1.pdf' not found`

Comment: Well, all you do is to show a screen shot that shows the contents of a directory. If you want help, provide us with a minimal document that shows what you are trying. `asypictureB` is a package, which allows you, similarly to the `asymptote` package, to embed some asymptote code in a LaTeX file. As explained in section **7 LaTeX usage** of the `asymptote` documentation, if you do not use `latexmk` you need to run `asy` between the `latex` compilations. With `asypictureB` you need to run `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I updated the original post to include the document code.

Comment: Thanks! How do you compile it?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I do `PdfLaTeX + Asymptote + PdfLaTeX + View Pdf`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sorry to bother you but I just realized something about the problem I have with labels in Asymptote. If I delete all of the files named `Document-1` or `Document-[Some number]` (i.e. all that's left is files named `Document`), and I quick build, it works fine with the labels. Thoughts on why this works but quick building without deleting those files doesn't?

Comment: My main problem is that I do have no experience whatsoever wit TeXmaker and such things. The asymptote package requires you, if I understand the manual correctly, to use either latexmk or to run asy by hand whenever you change something. Are you saying that latexmk does not update the asymptote files if you only change labels?